# Every element of $Z (\sqrt{-5})$ is factorable into irreducible factors.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to proof that each element of $R :=\mathbb{Z} (\sqrt{-5})$ is factorable into irreducible elements.

Let $x \in R, x = AB$ with $A = (a + b \sqrt{-5} ),$ $B = (c + d \sqrt{-5})$.

If $A = \pm 1$ or $B = \pm 1$ then $x$ irreducible and the proof is done.

Otherwise, $x = AB, N(x) = N(A) N(B)$ with $N(A),N(B)  \neq 1$.

How can I proceed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have the key to solving this in the property of the norm $N(x) = N(A)N(B)$ where $N(x)$ is an ordinary (rational) integer. Can the factoring process continue indefinitely?

Comment: You probably mean $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$

Comment: Okay, so both N(A) and N(B) are greater  than 1, thus N(x) > N(A), N(x)>N(B). So obviously the factoring process is finite and each reducible factor is getting smaller each time. And for N(R) is an integer, at some point the norm of every factor is 1 and hence irreducible. Is that correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your idea in the comment is right (see the third proof below).

An nonzero and noninvertible element $a$ of a domain $R$ fails to be a product of irreducible elements if, for every $b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n\in R$, with $b_i$ not invertible, at least one of the factors $b_i$ can be written as $b_i=cd$, where neither $c$ nor $d$ is invertible, that is, is not irreducible.

### First proof (with a big gun)

Assume $a$ is not a product of irreducibles. In what follows all elements I write as $a_{ij}$ are assumed to be noninvertible. Since $a=a_{11}$ is not irreducible, $a_{11}=a_{21}a_{22}$ and it's not restrictive to assume $a_{22}$ not irreducible, so we can factor it and get
$$
a_{11}=a_{21}a_{22}=a_{31}a_{32}a_{33}
$$
where the elements are reordered so that $a_{33}$ is not irreducible.
$$
a=a_{n1}a_{n2}\dotsm a_{nn} \tag{*}
$$
This allows us to build the increasing chain of ideals
$$
(a)=(a_{11})\subsetneq(a_{2i_2})\subsetneq\dots\subsetneq(a_{ni_n})
\subsetneq\dotsb
$$
where at each stage we choose one of the terms we factored, and therefore $R$ is not Noetherian.

The ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is a homomorphic image of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ via the isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]\cong\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+5)$, so it is Noetherian, because $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is Noetherian by Hilbert’s Basis theorem.

### Second proof (with just a bludgeon)

However, the specific case is easier. From (*), applying the norm function
$$
N(x+y\sqrt{-5})=x^2+5y^2
$$
we get
$$
N(a)=N(a_{n1})N(a_{n2})\dotsm N(a_{nn})
$$
where $N(a_{nj})>1$, for $j=1,2,\dots,n$. Since $N$ has (positive) integer values, this is a contradiction, because it would follow that
$$
N(a)\ge2^n
$$
for every $n\ge1$.

### Third proof (no big weapons)

Alternatively, do an induction on $N(a)$. If $N(a)=2$, the statement is (vacuously) true. Suppose it holds for every element $b$ with $2\le N(b)<N(a)$. Then either $a$ is irreducible and we are done, or $a=b_1b_2$, with $N(b_1)>1$ and $N(b_2)>1$; then $2\le N(b_1)<N(a)$ and $2\le N(b_2)<N(a)$ and the induction hypothesis applies.

### Comment

Why showing the big gun proof? Because the same result in every Noetherian domain, not just a simple integral extension of the integers.

Note however that *uniqueness* of factorization need not hold. In particular it doesn't hold in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, because
$$
6=2\cdot 3=(1+\sqrt{-5})(1+\sqrt{-5})
$$
where $2$ and $3$ are associate neither of $1+\sqrt{-5}$ nor of $1+\sqrt{-5}$.

Comment: The uniqueness of the factorization fails because there  is no Gauss lemma, and there is no Gauss lemma because $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ isn't principal, right ?

Comment: @Max Yes, it's not a PID, but that's not really required for being UFD.

Comment: +1. It's worth pointing out that the big gun shows that every noetherian domain is atomic.

Comment: The "big gun" approach does not really need to appeal to Hilbert's basis theorem. $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$ module. I think it is easier to prove that a finitely generated module over a Noetherian ring is Noetherian than Hilbert's basis theorem

Comment: @MatheiBoulomenos True, of course. But mentioning the big theorem seemed a good idea.

Comment: @egreg In the first (big gun) proof, how do you conclude that $a_{(n+1)1}$ properly divides $a_{n1}$? (It's true for $n = 1$ for $a_{11} = a_{21} a_{22}$, but I don't see how this is ensured for arbitrary $n$'s in your proof.)

Comment: @Atom Fixed, thanks for noting.